# Cookies are not authorized, we will not send any data. when trying to use Paystack inmy next app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, web-deployment

I keep getting this message when I am trying to use payStack in Next.js, And I have looked for any possible means to solve this but I haven't seen the solution to it

```
const componentProps = {
    email: userInfo.email,
    amount: totalPrice * 100,
    metadata: {
      name: shippingAddress?.fullName,
    },
   
    publicKey,
    text: "Pay Now",
    onSuccess: async () => {
      try {
        dispatch({ type: "PAY_REQUEST" });
        const { data } = await axios.put(
          `/api/orders/${order._id}/pay`,

          {
            headers: {
              authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
            },
          }
        );
        dispatch({ type: "PAY SUCESS", payload: data });
        alert("Thanks for doing business with us! Come back soon!!");
       
      } catch (error) {
        alert(getError(error));
      }
    },
    onClose: () => alert("Wait! Don't leave :("),
  };
```

And the message on my console is "Cookies are not authorized, we will not send any data."

This is the endpoint

```
import axios from "axios";
import nc from "next-connect";
import { isAuth } from "../../../../lib/auth";

const handler = nc();

handler.use(isAuth);

handler.put(async (req, res) => {
  const projectId = "projectId";
  const dataset = "dataset";
  const tokenWithAccess =token

  await axios.post(
    `https://${projectId}.api.sanity.io/v1/data/mutate/${dataset}`,
    {
      mutations: [
        {
          paths: {
            id: req.query.id,
            set: {
              isPaid: true,
              paidAt: new Date().toString(),
              "paymentResult.id": req.body.id,
              "paymentResult.status": req.body.email_address,
              "paymentResult..email_address": req.body.id,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenWithAccess}`,
      },
    }
  );
  res.send({ message: "Order Successfully" });
});

export default handler;
```

Here is my endpoint for the order information

Comment: What does that `/api/orders/....` endpoint do?

Comment: Store orders Information

Comment: Well, it's that endpoint that's giving you the error, so we can't much help without seeing it.

Comment: I will add add the endpoint code now

Comment: What does `isAuth` look like?